# Recursion Tracing

Tags: recursion

Lets assume I have a loop for Foo.

```
int Foo(int n)
{
   if (n <= 1)
      return 2;
   else
      return Foo(n-1) * Foo(n-2) * Foo (n-3);
}
```

How many call will occur If i Call Foo(3) and what would be the result...

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you run it and find out?

Comment: I need to be able to trade this by hand i am expecting something similar to this in the exam :D

Comment: 7 calls: http://ideone.com/0LU9T

Comment: How many calls occur? I am kind of confused...

Answer (score 6):

`Foo(3)` calls `Foo(2)`, `Foo(1)` and `Foo(0)`

`Foo(1)` and `Foo(0)` return immediately. Now apply the same logic for `Foo(2)`, which doesn't return immediately.

To get the result, draw a tree like this:

```
            Foo(3)
      /       |        \
   Foo(2)   Foo(1)   Foo(0)
```

Continue drawing the tree until you have recursive calls that return immediately (for which the first `if` returns true), then use those results to calculate the values that are higher in the tree.

You can use the tree to figure out how many recursive calls are made too.

Comment: @bubdada: Then, to make sure you understand, try it with Foo(5). Make a note of how many times you end up invoking the function for any given input value (i.e. how many times do you end up calling Foo(0), Foo(1), Foo(2), Foo(3), Foo(4), and Foo(5)?). For extra credit, figure out a way to cut down on the duplication, given that Foo should be returning the same value given the same input.

Answer (score 2):

Pass 1: Foo(3)

Pass 2: Foo(2) * Foo(1) * Foo(0)

Pass 3: Foo(1) * Foo(0) * Foo(-1) * 2 * 2

Result: 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 = 32

Answer (score 0):

Foo(3) would get called 7 times.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
int Foo(int n)
{
   cout << "Foo(" << n << ")" << endl;
   if (n <= 1)
      return 2;
   else
      return Foo(n-1) * Foo(n-2) * Foo (n-3);
}
```

Comment: I need to write more then 20 lines of code to be able to run on my system. Because we are using a crappy version of C++ but thanks thought...

Comment: @bubdada: You can't even use `printf`?